# BigCommerce: How can I customize CategoryProductListing

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to customize a product in the CategoryContent panel in BigCommerce. I want to change the markup for each product in the listing, but the markup for the entire product list is trapped in an uneditable blob :%%GLOBAL_CategoryProductListing%% (I'm getting really tired of these unchangable GLOBAL variables).

Is there any way around this so that I can put my own markup on each product in the list. I'm also open, reluctantly, to reconstruct the product list using the API, but I'm not sure how I can access the API from within a BigCommerce store. Is that possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to identify Snippets/CategoryProductsItem.html as the file containing the markup for the individual items in a category list.

I hope this saves someone the time it took me to find the file.

Comment: i am trying to edit the list of elements shown in this category list and want to add product attributes like size and color in this list view. Any tips ?

Answer (score 5):

The Snippets/CategoryProductsItem.html is the snippet used for grid category files. If you are using the list view, the file is Snippets/CategoryProductsItemList.html.

This file represents each product listing li. It acts as a template which loops through all the %%GLOBAL_CategoryProductListing%% information for this category. To add a feature to the category ProductList li add it to the Snippet, and it will be applied to each item.

Hope this helps.