# Using Big Commerce Product Custom Fields in Templates

Tags: bigcommerce

I have come to a road block in my search to the answer to using custom fields in templates.

I have tried adding

```
%%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%%
```

in the `ProductDescription.html` but nothing shows.

Is there ANY documentation about this?

Can this snippet be used in certain places only? if so which ones?

What needs to be in place for this to display in the products description?

Any help, tips or pointers would be great.

Comment: So this was a snippet you tried to create? Snippets aren't something that can be added by users. It requires development by BC as Snippets call to the core app to populate their data.

Comment: For including custom fields on the Category pages, see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856640/bigcommerce-how-can-i-customize-categoryproductlisting/33133740#33133740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CustomFields Snippet, `%%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%%`, can only be used if being referenced through its own **Panel**.

By default, the Panel that calls this snippet is named `%%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%`

You can also create your own custom Panels by uploading them to the `Panels` folder via WebDav.
For example, if you created a template file called `CustomFieldsPanel.html`, you would upload it to the `/dav/template/Panels` folder, and reference it in your theme by `%%Panel.CustomFieldsPanel%%`

---

To answer your question though, you can do one of the following to display Custom Fields in the Product Description:

1. Insert it into `ProductDescription.html` via its default Panel - `%%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%` - modifying it by editing the template file `ProductOtherDetails.html`
2. Create your own custom panel, include the Snippet within that same custom panel, and insert it into `ProductDescription.html` by the custom panel's name. An example of that file might look like so:

```
<!-- 
* /dav/template/Panels/MyCustomFieldsPanel.html 
* %%Panel.MyCustomFieldsPanel%%
-->
<div id="MyCustomFieldsPanel">
  <h1> Custom Fields Below </h1>
  %%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%%
</div>
```

[image]

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks love. I tried what you said but the  MyCustomfield didn't work. but the original Panel did `%%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%` It seam that Big Commerce only allows snippets with certain classes only.. but im not sure just a thought.

Comment: Glad to help. I've tested the custom panel on Classic Next (theme) and it worked for me, but maybe it varies per theme.